# C programming: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘Tipo {aka struct ElemSCl}

Tags: c

I'm learning, and this was a simple test.

### scl.h

```c
#ifndef sclh
#define sclh

typedef struct{
    int value; }listnote;


 struct ElemSCL {
       listnote info;
      struct ElemSCL*next;
                 };
                 
typedef struct ElemSCl Tipo;
typedef Tipo *Mangiato;


void Addscl(Mangiato*scl, int e) ;
#endif
```

### prove.c

```c
 #include "scl.h"
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<stdio.h>

//create node
void Addscl (Mangiato *scl, int e) {
 Mangiato temp;
 temp = *scl;
*scl= (Tipo*) malloc(sizeof(Tipo)); 
*(scl)->info.value= e;
*(scl)->next = temp;
   }
```

### Main.c

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include"scl.h"
int main()
{
    Tipo *scl= NULL;
    Addscl (&scl,3);
  printf("%d",  *(scl)->info.value);
      
        
    }
 return 0;
}
```

### I'm getting the following error:

```
main.c:9:22: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘Tipo {aka struct ElemSCl}’
 printf(" %d",  *(scl)->info.value);
                      ^~
prove.c: In function ‘Addscl’:
prove.c:9:29: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘Tipo {aka struct ElemSCl}’
 *scl= (Tipo*) malloc(sizeof(Tipo));
                             ^~~~
prove.c:10:7: error: ‘*scl’ is a pointer; did you mean to use ‘->’?
 *(scl)->info.value= e;
       ^~
       ->
prove.c:11:7: error: ‘*scl’ is a pointer; did you mean to use ‘->’?
 *(scl)->next = temp;
       ^~
       ->
```

Comment: **C and C++ are *different* programming languages**. If you code in C, read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/), then [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). If you code in C++ read a good [C++ programming book](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html) then [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). If you use the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler, read its documentation.

Comment: Take inspiration from the source code of existing open source software coded in C (e.g. [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) or [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or the [tiny C compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TinyCC)....)

Comment: Notice that [`malloc` can fail](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory) and your program don't handle that. It should.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `*(scl)->info.value` is the same as `*(scl->info.value)`. I.e. you dereference the `value` member.

You need `(*scl)->info.value` to dereference the `scl` pointer.

---

As for the `sizeof` problem, you have

```
 struct ElemSCL { ... };
```

and

```
typedef struct ElemSCl Tipo;
```

Pay close attention to the spelling... You use lower-case `l` in the `typedef`, it should be upper-case `L`:

```
typedef struct ElemSCL Tipo;
```

Comment: BTW, a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` would have warned several times